# Prisma export database & models

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

is there a way to create a dump of your database with the models, so that I can just push it on another database and just have to update my database address and all works out fine?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting from Prisma CLI itself is not possible as of now.

But what you can do is dump the db from the postgres cli.
And then Import the dump in your new DB : [Guide from Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/inserting-and-modifying-data/importing-and-exporting-data-in-postgresql)

Connect to this DB in your new application add a schema.prisma with base configuration, without models and pull the DB: [Introspection Guide from Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection#what-does-introspection-do)